# Categorise datetime type in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dataset as follows.

```
Sign-uptime                                                Part of Day
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-03 13:48:41
2015-02-06 19:42:33
2015-02-07 08:22:11 
2015-02-11 02:23:11 
2015-02-14 22:45:41
```

I already exported the dataset and i need to categorise as follows:

```
Morning     5 am to 12 pm (noon)
Afternoon   12 pm to 5 pm
Evening     5 pm to 9 pm
Night       9 pm to 5 am
```

and display these in the column "Part of Day". The signup time is of datetime type.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried...

Comment: I extracted the hour only (e.g 12.0) from the datetime and convert it to int (column name: Hours.Int). Then, I try

if merged_data['Hours.Int'].all() in range (1,5):
    print ('Night')
    
elif etc...

Comment: I tried this as well 

merged_data['Part_of_Day'] = numpy.where(int(12) <= merged_data['Hours.Int'].all() <= int(17), "Afternoon",0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below for my best soloution. Theres some difficulty with times crossing over the day... So i used a work around to split the 'night' ranges into 2 seperate ranges (AM, PM). See below:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

time_cats = {
'morning':(time(05,0,0), time(11,59,59)), 'afternoon':(time(12,0,0), time(16,59,59)),
'evening':(time(17,0,0), time(20,59,59)), 'night (PM)':(time(21,0,0), time(23,59,59)), 
'night (AM)':(time(0,0,0), time(04,59,59))
}

times_to_check = [
'2015-02-03 13:48:41',
'2015-02-06 19:42:33',
'2015-02-07 08:22:11', 
'2015-02-11 02:23:11',
'2015-02-14 22:45:41'
]

for check in times_to_check:
    check_time = datetime.strptime(check, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").time()
    for k, v in time_cats.iteritems():
        if v[0] <= check_time <= v[1]:
            print check, k
```

Comment: Should have probably worked this into a function taking list of times to check and the 'time_cats' dictionary!

Comment: Thanks. I tried the below and it works.

merged_data.loc[merged_data['Hours_Int'].isin(range(1,5)) , 'Part_of_Day'] = '3' #Night
merged_data.loc[merged_data['Hours_Int'].isin(range(5,12)) , 'Part_of_Day'] = '0' #Morning
merged_data.loc[merged_data['Hours_Int'].isin(range(12,17)) , 'Part_of_Day'] = '1' #Afternoon
merged_data.loc[merged_data['Hours_Int'].isin(range(17,21)) , 'Part_of_Day'] = '2' #Evening
merged_data.loc[merged_data['Hours_Int'].isin(range(21,25)) , 'Part_of_Day'] = '3' #Night